# combining two sorted arrays while keeping track of individual indexes in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have two pair of arrays. In each pair one array contains the index values referring to another result array while 2nd array contains the score. These are sorted, so that for example in pair one, i can select the 3 best high scores from Array-2 and they will correspond to indexes no 3,7 and 4 respectively.

Now the idea is to combine such pairs e.g Pair-1 and Pair-2, sort them and then select 3 best values.
Like if you see the picture below, in the sorted value array in result the first two highest values correspond to index number 1&6 in array from Pair-2 while 3rd value correspond to index 3 of array from Pair-1.
[image]

It would be nice if you could give me some idea about how can i keep track of index numbers of respective arrays in the sorted result. I know how to sort them but really don't know how to go about keeping track of these individual arrays.

Comment: Is this homework?  Where is the picture referenced?

Comment: no not homework, i just made it in order to clarify my question. I don't need code i just need idea how to do it. Also in my application i don't have two pairs rather it is of the order of 15-18 array pairs coming of which i have to sort and select 5-6 best values. and correspoding to these values, i have to find indexes in respective arrays. These indexes will futher refer to some obejcts which is the main thing i want to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think in objects.

If you create a `Pair` object that has index, value and source array properties you can make it `Comparable` on the value.

Create `Pair` objects from your arrays, put them in a `List` then [sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) it.

Comment: thanks a lot. It makes sense, i tried and it works like a treat. Thank you again :)))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Hashtable?

```
Hashtable<Integer, Pair> sortedTable = new Hashtable<Integer, Pair>();

for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) { //if the 2 arrays are equal in length
    sortedTable.put(sortedTable.size(), new Pair(firstArray[i], secondArray[i]));
}
```